# Do view functions cause reentrancy vulnerabulity?

Tags: security, interfaces, reentrant-attacks, vulnerability, view

It's well known that calling an external function before changing something in the contract causes a security problem called "reentrancy vulnerability".

Does calling an external function through a view member of an interface cause reentrancy vulnerability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calls through `view` members of interfaces are done through `STATICCALL` opcode. As my experiment confirmed Solidity 0.6.0 does use `STATICCALL` in this case.

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-214.md

> To increase smart contract security, this proposal adds a new opcode that can be used to call another contract (or itself) while disallowing any modifications to the state during the call (and its subcalls, if present).

So, there is no such vulnerability in the current versions of Solidity.

However, old versions of Solidity *are* vulnerable. See [this Ethereum pull request](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper/pull/237) for the change done in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Funnily enough I just came searching for an answer to this myself. As I understand it, there is no reentrancy vulnerability in a conventional sense because a view member cannot modify state.

Comment: But can a modifying function be called through a `view` interface member?

Answer (score 1):

View functions cannot modify the state, as specified [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.6/contracts.html#view-functions). It means that they cannot make any permanent change to the blockchain such as changing the ether or tokens balances. Therefore, reentrancy is not an issue with View functions.

Comment: But can a modifying function be called through a `view` interface member?

Comment: A view function cannot call a function that is not itself a view or pure function, so no (see the documentation linked in the answer).

Comment: I asked about a view interface member, not about a view function.

Comment: Aren't interface just functions without implementation? They don't do anything until they are implemented, and then become view functions that cannot change the state.

Comment: My question is what happens if a hacker passes to my user a contract with non-view function through my view interface member.